# libcurl crashing program after execution?

Tags: c++, c, curl

I am using libcurl to make request google server. The curl library is giving output , when i use curl variables as global every thing works fine but when i am using the curl variables as local inside a function or a class private members the program crashes. I am not able to catch where segmentation fault occurring.

Code is

```
void func1();
{
    Internet_connection_through_curl    internet_connection;
    internet_connection.simple_program(query_url);
}

Internet_connection_through_curl::simple_program(string url)
{
    CURL *curle;
    CURLcode rese;
    curle = curl_easy_init();

    if(curle)
    {
        curl_easy_setopt(curle, CURLOPT_URL, url.c_str());
        curl_easy_setopt(curle, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1L);
        curl_easy_setopt(curle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0L);
        curl_easy_setopt(curle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0L);
        curl_easy_setopt(curle, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA , (void *)(&UF));
        curl_easy_setopt(curle, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, WriteMemoryCallback);
        curl_easy_setopt(curle, CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION, HeaderMemoryCallback);
        rese = curl_easy_perform(curle);
        fprintf(stderr , "Curl easy perform error----> %s\n" , curl_easy_strerror(rese));
        if(rese != CURLE_OK)
               fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",curl_easy_strerror(rese));
        curl_easy_cleanup(curle);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried running in a debugger? And when the crash occurs use the `up` command of GDB to walk up the call-stack until you come to your code?

Comment: How do `WriteMemoryCallback` and `HeaderMemoryCallback` look like?

Comment: A fully compilable code is useful when asking questions like this, that way we can see EXACTLY what the issue is